# How long will it take for my app in google play store to be unpublished?

Tags: google-play, publishing

How long does it take for my app to be publicly unpublished - unavaiable ?
It is going to be immediately unavailable after I confirm unpublish inside google play console ? or It will take some time just like other updates to be reflected worldwide - and how long would that time be ?

I couldn't find documentation about this in google help.
Thank You.

Comment: Contact the google support for this, I don't know either

Comment: can't find details about time needed for unpublish action to reflect worldwid.

Answer (score 2):

It will be always available to users who already downloaded your app, so they can get updates for it, but it will be permanently invisible to any new users. All the answers you need are here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=en

Comment: Yes I know. I am talking about the time (duration) it will take for my app to disappear form market after I choose to unpublished it... ?